# How to get browser full screen width for my html page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap 3.3.5 in my grails application.

But the problem is my gsp view is not showing in full screen.

How do i make this in full screen without interfering bootstrap responsive feature.

> I wrote my main.gsp inside

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

class `.container-fluid` have right and left padding in bootstrap.
you need to override it by creating new class which have style:

```
padding-right:0px;
padding-left:0px;
```

example:

```
<div class="container-fluid full">
</div>

.full{
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    margin:0;
}
```